# Go & PHP json-rpc communication

Tags: php, go, json-rpc

I try communication JSON-RPC between php and go.

Server GO from this example https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "net/rpc"
    "net"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Args struct {
    A, B int
}

type Quotient struct {
    Quo, Rem int
}

type Arith int

func (t *Arith) Multiply(args *Args, reply *int) error {
    *reply = args.A * args.B
    return nil
}

func (t *Arith) Divide(args *Args, quo *Quotient) error {
    if args.B == 0 {
        return errors.New("divide by zero")
    }
    quo.Quo = args.A / args.B
    quo.Rem = args.A % args.B
    return nil
}


func main() {
    arith := new(Arith)
    rpc.Register(arith)
    rpc.HandleHTTP()
    l, e := net.Listen("tcp", ":4444")
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("listen error:", e)
    }
//  go http.Serve(l, nil)

    err:= http.Serve(l, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error serving: %s", err)
    }

}
```

and php client from example this repository https://github.com/ptcx/jsonrpc-client:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new JRClient\Client('tcp', '127.0.0.1:4444');
sleep(5);
$result = $client->call('Arith.Multiply', ['A' => 3, "B" => 4], 1000);
if ($result['error']) {
    echo $result['errorMsg'] . "\n";
} else {
    var_dump($result['data']);
}
```

Bur final I have error: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
I tried also write `sleep(5)` after php connect but no result? Also  I tried change from `true` on `false` into function `stream_set_blocking($this->sockfp, false)` https://github.com/ptcx/jsonrpc-client/blob/master/src/Connection/TcpConnection.php#L69   - no result. 
I treed write  GO client - it is worked without problem.

Help me please with my php client

Comment: A 400 response means there was a bad request, and a _response_, so it's not about connecting or blocking. Have you looked at the actual requests from each client to see how they differ?

Comment: @JimB good idea. But how I can do it differ, which way ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. These are fairly simple requests, you should be able to spot any differences visually by just looking at them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `rpc.HandleHTTP()`, you are using gobs encode and decode. Read more about gobs in: https://blog.golang.org/gobs-of-data and https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/.

In file https://golang.org/src/net/rpc/server.go you can read this:

[image]

To use jsonrpc in Go, you must use the codec from package net/rpc/jsonrpc instead of net/rpc.

> Package jsonrpc implements a JSON-RPC 1.0 ClientCodec and ServerCodec
>   for the rpc package. For JSON-RPC 2.0 support [...]
>
> (Ref. source: https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/jsonrpc/)

So above following the code in main.go:

```
func main() {
    //arith instance
    arith := new(Arith)

    //make listen in 127.0.0.1:4444
    l, e := net.Listen("tcp", ":4444")
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("listen error:", e)
    }
    defer l.Close()

    //instance rpc server
    rpcserver := rpc.NewServer()
    rpcserver.Register(arith)
    //updated for multiples requests
    for {
        //block until acceptation of client
        c, e := l.Accept()
        if e != nil {
          log.Fatal("accept error:", e)
        }
        //instance codec
        jsoncodec := jsonrpc.NewServerCodec(c)
        rpcserver.ServeCodec(jsoncodec)
    }
}
```

On exec `php client.php` the result was:

[image]

Update: in php file:

```
<?php
//imports
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
//instance client
$client = new JRClient\Client('tcp', '127.0.0.1:4444');

//sleep(5); <<-- remove

//call method 'Arith.Multiply'
$result = $client->call('Arith.Multiply', ['A' => 3, "B" => 4], 1000);
if ($result['error']) {
    echo $result['errorMsg'] . "\n";
} else {
    var_dump($result['data']);
}

?>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for help, but if I run php client first time with you new code on go server, I get error  {"id":1,"result":null,"error":"rpc: can't find service Arith.Multiply"}

 https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/rpc/server.go#L614

and second time:  "time out error"

go version go1.9.4 linux/amd64
and php 5.6